# Using Python 3.6 with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythoninterpreter

I'm trying to use the Pool.starmap() function with multiprocessing, but it is only available in Python 3.3+. My Python default version is 2.7.10, but I also have installed Python 3.6. I've tried changing the selected Python interpreter in the command palette and even it says its now currently using the 3.6 interpreter it outputs the following:

```
AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'starmap'
```

I've tried restarting VS Code but it didn't work. I've looked up to see if updating the default Python version in the OS might help but it seems that it is not a good idea. Any ideas?

Edit: My OS is macOS  HighSierra Version 10.13.2

Comment: You can use `import sys; print(sys.version)` inside your Python code to verify that the correct version is being used.

Answer (score -1):

To the top of your file, add a "shebang" (a comment starting with a bang) with the path to your python 3.6 interpreter, which in my case is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

Then click on "Set as interpreter" directly above it.

[image: "Set as interpreter" prompt]

Comment: Don't include links to external images, and don't use images to show code; answers can use code block formatting for showing code, and answers can directly include images.

Comment: @Evert fixed it. I used the builtin image button but on the first try it created a link instead of adding an image inline, so I went with it. After some markdown research, I was able to get it to inline it

Comment: Note that that it's still better to use a code block here: visually impaired people and people using a text-only browser can read a code block, but can't see the image.

Comment: How do you suggest I depict "Set as interpreter", which is an IDE thing, in a code block without confusing someone? Or do I just include the shebang in a code block

Comment: `[[Set as interpreter]]` perhaps? It doesn't need to be actually running code. If the text and position matches the actual GUI, that would work nicely. Alternatively, you don't really need the image, and could just decribe it ('...click on "Set as interpreter" directly above it.').

Answer (score -1):

You know, the best way is to **uninstall python 2.7.10, install python 3.6.**

When installing python 3.6, Be careful about **default settings.**

Comment: Python 2.7.10 is probably the system-default Python. It would be unwise to uninstall that. Besides, it is totally unnecessary.